# How can I get equal lan lat grids using WGS84 with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, wgs84

I use am familiar with R and ArcGIS pro. I want to plot maps using WGS84 in R using ggplot.

I get equal lat Lon grids in ArcGIS pro while zooming to, say, Germany. But I am not able to get equal grids in R using ggplot2 using WGS84.

Following is what I am trying:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("terra")
library("sf")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
world_projected <- st_transform(world, crs("epsg:4326"))

ggplot(data = world_projected) +
  geom_sf(fill = "transparent") +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = alpha("black", 0.1), linewidth=1, linetype = 1)
  ) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(5, 16), ylim = c(46, 56), default_crs = crs("epsg:4326"))
```

What I get in ArcGIS Pro

[image]

What I get in R

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Pallav

Comment: your code is not reproducible. `Error in crs("epsg:4326") : could not find function "crs"`

Comment: Are you loading the `terra` package?

Comment: @Wimpel thanks for checking the code. I have added lines that loads "terra" and "sf" packages from library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to plot an [equidistant cylindrical](https://epsg.io/4087) projection. This is straightforward, but you will need to convert your x and y range to the correct projection too:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

coords <- st_sf(a = 1:2, geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(5, 46)), st_point(c(16, 56))), 
                crs = 4326) |>
                st_transform(crs = 4087) |>
                st_coordinates()

ggplot(data = st_transform(world, crs = 4087)) +
  geom_sf(fill = "transparent") +
  coord_sf(xlim = coords[,1], ylim = coords[,2]) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = alpha("black", 0.1), 
                                        linewidth = 1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of "coords". Why can't we just transform "world" from 4326 to 4087 and plot right away? (which didn't work for me and led to weird coordinates labels)

Comment: I realised that the x/ylims in coord_sf requires the values in EPSG 4087 and not lat Lon, so "coords" was necessary. Thanks Allan.

Answer (score 1):

an other option can be to drop the crs all together.. this will autimatically create a square (numeric) grid to plot on

```
ggplot(data = world %>% sf::st_set_crs(NA)) +
  geom_sf(fill = "transparent") +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = alpha("black", 0.1), linewidth=1, linetype = 1)
  ) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(5, 16), ylim = c(46, 56), default_crs = crs("epsg:4326"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I tried adding a shape file to the map after stripping off the crs from it too. Seems to work fine. 

I am just wondering that this method must have some drawbacks... a minor one could be that the lat Lon labels don't have direction and circ anymore...